# Print an array, without knowing the size

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have this function:

```
int printArray(int* arr, int size) {

    int i = 0;
    while (size--) {
        printf("%d, ", *(arr + i++));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How can I print the array without using the **size** parameter?

L.E. I tried to do something like this:

```
int printArray(int* arr) {

    int i = 0;
    while (*(arr + i)) {
        printf("%d, ", *(arr + i++));
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

but every output is followed by three unknown values: (**in**: 1 2 3 4; **out**: 1 2 3 4 343443 -432244 324333).

Thanks!

Comment: Dunno.  In general, you can't.  Is there some illegal value in your set of ints that could be used as a sentinel?  -1, maybe?

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: `while (*(arr + i)) { ... }` is a buffer overflow - you are reading into memory that was not meant for you, and only stopping when `arr + i` happens to point to the value `0`!

Comment: you second code sample is what the compiler calls 'undefined behavior', you ran off the end of the array hoping that what was there was a NULL. It usally isnt (as you saw)

Comment: @H2CO3 I learn pointers, and I want to experiment all variants.

Comment: @pm100 Thanks, now I really understand what is with that last values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass in the address to the last element:

```
int printArray(int* arr, int* end) {

    do {
        printf("%d, ", *arr);
    } while( (arr++) != end);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An array is simply a series of contiguous memory locations. In order to traverse an array you need to know two things, the starting address and how to find the end.

Finding the end can be done in a few ways, you need to be given:

1. the ending address explicitly
2. the length of the array
3. a sentinel value used to mark the end of the sequence

In your first attempt, `printArray(int* arr, int size)` is using the second mechanism and incrementing memory locations from the start to the end.

Your second attempt `printArray(int* arr)` simply states "print until a 0 is found". This idea would work fine if you had a string (a `char` array ended with a null terminator), but you have an array of `int`s. There is no guarantee that 0 is in that list, so you'll just keep reading more and more memory locations until one finally has a 0.

Writing a program is very akin to the normal human thought process. Simple read your code and see if it makes sense:

```
int in[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};  // I have an array called in, it has 4 numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4
int ret = printArray(in);  // I pass that array to the function printArray

...
while (*(arr + i)) {       // while the contents of the memory location (array + i) is
                           // not 0, print the value we find there
```

Suddenly it becomes very obvious why this doesn't work. Did your array contain the number 0? Nope... so when will it stop printing?

Answer (score 1):

add a sentinel value. A value that you know is always the last one. Tough for ints, but -1 and 0 are favorite values.

Comment: `INT_MAX` (or `INT_MIN`) is also an option.