# printing a unknown 2D array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to stackoverflow.

I have a 2D array of strings with unknown size like this.

```
   char **table = NULL;
   table = myfunc();   // Table now contains something like {"Merry","Leo","Linus"...}
```

Is there a way to print this array with a loop like this?

```
   int i = 0;
   while(????){   // Is there a condition i can use here to loop the list? 
        printf("%s", table[i]);
        i++;
   }
```

So i get the output below.

```
Merry
Leo
Linus
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you must have size info of the array.

Comment: There is no way until and unless there is a sentinel at the end of the array of strings (or whatever is the data structure).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print an array, without knowing the size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358986/print-an-array-without-knowing-the-size)

Comment: There is no array in your code, let alone any array sizes.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

Other options:

1. Pass the address of a variable to the function and set it to the number of elements in the array from the function:

   ```
   char **table = NULL;
   size_t n;
   table = myfunc(&n);
   ```

   Then, the conditon could be:

   ```
   while(i < n) { … }
   ```
2. Mark the end of the array with some special value, say, `NULL`:

   ```
   char **table = NULL;
   table = myfunc(); // Table now contains something like {"Merry","Leo","Linus", …, NULL}
   ```

   Then, the conditon could be:

   ```
   while(table[i]) { … }
   ```

Note: In both these alternatives, don't forget to make `i` a `size_t`.

Comment: The second method is a god solution I'm going to use it. Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sentinel. Modify your `myfunc` to add an `NULL` after the last element. Your array looks like `{"Merry", "Leo", ...., NULL}`

Now, you can iterate like that :

```
int i = 0;

while (table[i] != NULL)
{
    printf("%s", table[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Be careful, with solutions based on sentinels, you can have some trouble, like with string: Are you sure the sentinel are correctly set, *ie* is the data source is safe? If not, I encourage you to add a limit : `while(i < MAX && table[i] != NULL)`.

Comment: God point. I'm going to add a safety feature to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model that is used by the C Standard in function main.

The standard declaration of the main is

```
int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   //...
}
```

`argv[argc]` is always equal to NULL. Using this fact you can for example output all parameters of the main the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    while ( *argv ) puts( *argv++ );
}
```

So what you need for your program is that the array of strings has the last element equal to `NULL`.

In this case you can write

```
   char **table = NULL;
   table = myfunc();

   for ( char **p = table; *p; ++p ) puts( *p );
```

Another way is to write the function such a way that it would also report the number of elements in the array. In this case the function can be declared either like

```
size_t myFunc( char ***table );
```

or like

```
char ** myFunc( size_t *n );
```

and called like

```
size_t n = myFunc( &table );
```

or

```
size_t n;

table = myFunc( &n );
```